# Login page using Mvvmcross

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, mvvmcross

I'm writing an application for Android, iPhone, WinRT and WinPhone that requires the user to login first (they may save their credentials so this step may need to be omitted after the initial login).

I know I can register the login view model as the start page, but then I would need to remove it from the back stack when the user completes the login to prevent navigation back to it.

So instead I decided I would navigate to the FirstVM, and if there are now cached credentials I would navigate to the Login VM. The LoginVM would just call close and use a message to inform the FirstVM it may continue as normal.

I'm doing the initial implementation as a WinRT app, and the two issues I have with the second option are:-

1. There appears to be no good event to use to navigate to the login VM from the FirstMV. Start would be the obvious choice, but this won't allow a navigation so I have had to do the following:

   ```
   public async override void Start()
   {
       base.Start();
       await Task.Delay(1);
       ShowViewModel<LoginViewModel>();            
   }
   ```

   There must be a better method!
2. When I call close on the LoginViewModel the message I sent is recieved by the FirstVM, but WinRT creates a new FirstVM and navigates to that instance, instead of the one initially created.

There is probably a much better way to do all of this anyway!

Thanks

Ross

Answer (score 1):

WinRT has a different default navigation model to WinPhone/Silverlight

There's a good explanation of it on http://mikaelkoskinen.net/winrt-navigation-cache-or-why-going-back-to-previous-page-creates-a-new-instance-of-the-page/ - including how to mimic WinPhone